# retrieving dictionary elements by index rather than key

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have a counter. With the counter, I do a `counter.most_common()`

However, all I really need from this counter is the top, say, five elements. Would there be a way to retrieve from it by index rather than by key? ie, `counter[0]` for the top element

Is this possible?

Comment: You want to get the top 5 most common elements?

Comment: Python dictionaries are unordered. You would need to use [ordereddict](http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict)

Comment: Nope. Python has no order on dictionaries.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`most_common(...)` takes in an argument.

```
>>> a = collections.Counter('abcdababc')
>>> a.most_common()
[('a', 3), ('b', 3), ('c', 2), ('d', 1)]
>>> a.most_common(2)
[('a', 3), ('b', 3)]
```

Answer (score 3):

[`most_common`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) already does this.  `counter.most_common(5)` is the top five elements and their counts.

Answer (score 1):

If you are set on use indices, you can try converting the dictionary into a list and then fetch the `(key,value)` tuple by index.

```
counter.items()[0]
```

Comment: This doesn't work.  `items` returns the contents and their counts in arbitrary order, not sorted by count.